# Does a hero lose the experience if he/she dies?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

As you fight with your heroes, they grow in experience and level up. Does a hero lose the experience gained during that match if he or she gets defeated (life reaches 0)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this appears to be exactly the case. See [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/fireemblem/comments/5rqpbu/psa_the_death_penalty_in_fire_emblem_heroes_is_a/):

> #### PSA: The death penalty in Fire Emblem Heroes is a loss of any xp or level ups gained for that unit in the map.
>
> Camilla died on a map after leveling to 11. Even though the rest of the team completed the level, she was lvl 10 in the next map.
>
> Also, you can't "reroll" bad level ups with this method. You'll get the same stat growths next time you level, you just lose the xp.

Comment: probably assigns an rng seed to each character, which will always produce the same results in the same order. (that is, your stat changes are determined on creation of the hero forever)

Comment: @Cruncher the other Fire Emblem games - at least the ones released in the West, so starting with Blazing Blade - do the same thing for all RNG-decided things. For instance, if you save mid-battle, then attack an enemy and miss, re-loading your save and making the same attack will always be a miss.

Comment: @Walt most games use a 1-seed per save model, but what you're talking about makes it sound like it has a different seed for each(or at least multiple) type. Otherwise any other rng event happening at all in the game, would change the value of that miss. Like in pokemon how they do rng manipulatin by stepping a certain number of steps in tall grass as each step is a random event of an encounter

Comment: @Cruncher I haven't tested it in-depth, though I'm sure someone has. That said, I think all random events are triggered by attacking, and if you're in a situation where you're depending on the outcome of a single RNG roll, you may not be able to waste a move (and risk a counterattack) trying to change the RNG.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, heroes lose experience on death.

Comment: Seeing as how classic Fire Emblem has permadeath, losing a bit of XP is a pretty minor inconvenience.